# Tools Vs Advanced Settings Icon

Tags: design, interface, users, ux-designer

I am designing a paint app in which I am not sure about the two Icons I am using. One is called Tools and the other is advanced settings. When you tap on the tools: Brush, Eraser and advanced Settings open up.(So, advanced Settings is a subcategory of Tools). And, when you tap on Advanced Settings: lighting, Hue, Saturation,...open up. 
So, I am not sure what Icon can I use for Advanced Setting and What Icon to use for Tools to make them clear. I am thinking to use the gear icon for tools. But,then what to use for advanced settings?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The terminology you are using is **incorrect**.

Instead of terming Image Processing functions consisting of Hue, Saturation, Contrast, Brightness, etc as *Advanced Settings*, a better option is to name it **Edit** or **Tune Image**.

Why? Because major photo editing apps do this. Instagram and Snapseed both use an Edit icon for tuning the image with image processing functions you mentioned above. A simple pencil icon or magic wand could do the trick.

You could then name the actual Tools as Settings and complement it with a Gear icon.

Comment: Well, brush and erase are part of edit too. So, I cannot rename Adv Settings /More Tools with Edit

Answer (score 0):

If 'Advanced Settings', sits under 'Tools', then you could use the gear icon for Tools and the three dot icon for advanced settings (...)

It's kind of like opening the toolbar, and then you can dig deeper into the toolset if you want. I think any kind of 'expand' type icon could work here. You don't really need to find an icon for advanced settings, just one to help show context.

In this case I would say that your context is "Here are some tools, and if you want, you can click here for some more tools". If the hierarchy was different or if 'tools' and 'advanced settings' were at the same level, then the context would change. But I think this works for your situation.

Comment: Thanks @user85892 - if you are happy with the answer please up vote it, or if it's the answer you will use, please accept it as well

Answer (score 0):

"Tools", in the context of an image editing application, are typically **local** operations.  That is, they are actions that the user does by clicking (or pressing) on the canvas (e.g. draw, select, erase, zoom). It's generally understood that you select a tool, and that the selected tool governs how the user interacts directly with the canvas.

On the other hand, Lighting/Saturation/Hue/etc. are applied to the image (or layer, or selected area of the canvas) on a **global** scale.

Using these definitions, I would not classify Lighting/Hue/Saturation as "Tools", but instead put them under some other category (something like "Image Adjustments").

Comment: This answer assumes that your Lighting/Hue/Saturation functions are global scale.

Comment: I see the point. m